# How do you use `BeApproximately` with a value that changes in each iteration of a loop?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

#### Description

- I'm iterating over 2 lists
- I want to compare the 2 values at each point in the list
- I want the value to be within 0.1% of each other

#### Complete minimal example reproducing the issue

```cs
var sheetRows = new List<float> { -24.0, 0.1, 10};
var loads= new List<float> { -24.0, 0.1, 10.05};
foreach ((var xl, var db) in sheetRows.Zip(loads, (n, w) => (n, w)))
{
   xl.Should().BeApproximately(db, db*0.001f);
}
```

#### Expected behavior:

To pass

#### Actual behavior:

```
Expected xl to approximate -24F +/- -0.024F, but -24F differed by 0F.
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.LateBoundTestFramework.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
   at FluentAssertions.NumericAssertionsExtensions.FailIfDifferenceOutsidePrecision[T](Boolean differenceWithinPrecision, NumericAssertions`1 parent, T expectedValue, T precision, T actualDifference, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at FluentAssertions.NumericAssertionsExtensions.BeApproximately(NumericAssertions`1 parent, Single expectedValue, Single precision, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at RoutingTests.UnitResponseModuleTests.U010_CheckTranslationAsync(Int64 sId, String sheetName, Int32 expected, Int32 excelRowCount) in C:\Users\sogscx\source\repos\Float\Compute\Test\RoutingTests\UnitResponseModuleTests.cs:line 480
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
```

#### Versions

- Which version of Fluent Assertions are you using?

latest

- Which .NET runtime and version are you targeting? E.g. .NET framework 4.6.1 or .NET Core 2.1.

.NET Core 3.1 running NUnit

Comment: @DTul, I know that works. I want a deviation per value. i.e. float values only have 6 to 8 digits so if it is 10000, and another 0.001, then 10% is different for each !

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a negative value for the precision. That's most likely not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.. 
Shows that there is a need for Argument validation in Fluent-assertions